# What is difference in following two setState

Tags: reactjs, state

I am bit confused in behavior of following two types of setting state, can anyone please elaborate both types?

Type 1

```
testFunction1(val){
    this.setState({value : val});
}
```

Type 2

```
testFunction2(value){
    this.setState({value});
}
```

here,

```
this.state={value:[]};
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

They're actually the same `setState`, the 2nd one just uses ES6's [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), in which the variable name becomes the property name, and the variable value becomes the property value:

```
var a = "foo", b = 42, c = {};
var o = { a, b, c }; // o => { a: "foo", b: 42, c: {} }
```

So this:

```
testFunction2(value){
    this.setState({value});
}
```

is translated to this:

```
testFunction2(value){
    this.setState({ value: value });
}
```

Comment: but both were giving different results first one was storing state as `value:[{val:"test"}{val:"test2"}]` and second one was storing as `value: ["test1","test2"]

Comment: What were your original `val` and `value`? How did you use them? Add that to your question.

Comment: i was using react-select of jade watson. in which I tried using first type on onChange function.

Comment: Clearly `val` is an object, while value is a primitive (string). You can `console.log(value)` and `console.log(val)`, and see it. What does your options array look like?

Comment: `[
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];
`